# Monitoring service status on GCP VM

Tags: google-cloud-platform, monitoring

I have project on GCP with a VM instance in it (CentOS 7). I want to monitor the status of some services running on the VM. Is there a way to monitor them through the OPS agent?

The objective would then be to have alerts based on the status of the service (using Grafana). Using `agent.googleapis.com/processes/cpu_time` in the [GCP process metrics](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/agent/process-metrics) does show the processes currently running on the VM, but having an alert based on the CPU time of a process is not clear cut as having an alert based on the status of a service.

Also I have a hard-time finding an answer to what the difference between a service and process is in UNIX. Based on this answer https://superuser.com/questions/1235647/what-is-the-difference-between-a-service-and-a-process it seems that a service differs in that it runs continuously(?)

Does this mean that monitoring the processes associated to the service is not the same as monitoring the service itself, since the process may be killed but the service continue running?

Answer (score 1):

You can setup custom alert on any running process on GCP.

In Alert policy you need to add Process name ( .exe process path).

Please go through below video. Explained in Details.

https://youtu.be/aaa_kwM7zkA